# sed with negative lookahead in file

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of a string (str) that are not adjacent to an underscore in a file with another string (replacementstr). This does not work-

```
sed -i 's/^(?!_str_|_str|str_)(str)$/replacementstr/g' /home/somefile.txt
```

Comment: can you put a sample data and your expected output?

Comment: Which specific version of `sed`? POSIX-baseline sed doesn't support PCRE extensions.

Comment: (`sed -i`, incidentally, is _also_ a non-POSIX extension; the POSIX-standardized in-place editing tools are `ed` and `ex` -- and if you know how to use vim in command mode, you already know `ex`).

Comment: OK will do. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need negative lookahead at all for this -- and your resulting state machine will be more efficient without it (meaning you're better off not using it even if your engine *did* support them).

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^_])str([^_]|$)/\1replacement\2/g'
```

Comment: Nice! probably worth mentioning you need `-r` to be able to catch without escaping the parentheses.

Comment: Quite right, that. I was avoiding going into usage because I don't want to (even implicitly) endorse `-i`, but since I'm giving an ERE, it's rather unavoidable.